# Hibernate connect to multiple database with same tables

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate, database-migration

I have to connect to two databases (PostgreSQL , Oracle) which contains same tables.
When I create entities of same tables in different packages it doesn't work.

Even though using two database connections the application always points to one database connection only.

Is it possible in Hibernate to connect to same tables from different databases?

**application.properties**

```
#DataSource settings for Postgres
datasource.secondary.url =jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/****
datasource.secondary.username =postgres
datasource.secondary.password =Postgre@1234
datasource.secondary.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.secondary.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#DataSource settings for oracle
datasource.primary.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
datasource.primary.username = ***
datasource.primary.password = ***
datasource.primary.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleDBConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oracleDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "postgresDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

**Primary**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
            transactionManagerRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
            basePackages = {"com.ubl.model.*"})
public class PrimaryDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.ubl.model.migration.entity.oracle"});
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("customers");

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalJpaProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe")
                .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
                .username("****")
                .password("****")
                .build();
    }   

    @Bean(name = "primarytransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory customerEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(customerEntityManager);

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**Secondary**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.ubl.*"})
public class SecondaryDBConfig {

    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Value("${datasource.secondary.url}")
    private String databaseURL; 

    @Value("${datasource.secondary.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${datasource.secondary.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${datasource.secondary.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${datasource.secondary.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    public SecondaryDBConfig() {
        System.out.println("Secondary repository");
        System.out.println("driverClassName: *************" +driverClassName);
    }

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(databaseURL, username, password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.ubl.model.*");   // package for entities
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("secondaryPersistenceUnit");
        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }


}
```

When I run the application I get below error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SchemaExtractionException: More than one table found in namespace (, )

Answer (score 0):

Your second config appears to use the same namespace as your first:

```
basePackages = {"com.ubl.model.*"}
basePackages = {"com.ubl.*"}
```

Once your second config looks for it's entities, it discovers the same as the fist does and thus resulting in the exception. You will want to separate your entities and both your configs.

```
basePackages = {"com.ubl.model.datasource1"}
basePackages = {"com.ubl.model.datasource2"} // well you get the idea and will find better names ;)
```

Then move all your entities in the respective folder. Although the table are "the same" you need one @Entity-Class for each individual Table, even though the tables you will want to use are structurally identical.